# Horizontal alignment of 3 elements in footer of a PDF output from RMarkdown using LaTex

Tags: fancyhdr, r

How do I fix the horizontal alignment of my footer in a PDF file produced from an R Markdown using LaTex?

Here's my header.tex file:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\newcommand {\changefont} {%
  \fontsize{6}{8}\selectfont
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[LE, LO]{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{image1.png}}
\fancyfoot[CE, CO]{\changefont This is the placeholder for the middle footer text that is very lengthy and occupies at least 3 lines}
\fancyfoot[RE, RO]{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{image2.png}}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancy}}
```

And my RMD file has the following yaml:

```
---
  title: "PDF Outpuf File"
output: 
  pdf_document:
  includes:
  in_header: Span_Data_Explorer/header.tex
---
```

How do I make the footer so that they're well-aligned horizontally (either bottom-, center-, or top-aligned)?

This is what I want my footer to look like (in-general).

[image]

But my bare pdf output looks like this (sorry had to blur the images and actual text). 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For center and bottom aligned, you can place the contents of the footer items inside minipages like this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\newcommand {\changefont} {\fontsize{6}{8}\selectfont}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[LE, LO]{
\begin{minipage}[c]{1.55cm}\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image-b}\end{minipage}}
\fancyfoot[CE, CO]{\begin{minipage}[c]{.6\textwidth}\changefont This is the placeholder for the middle footer text that is very lengthy and occupies at least 3 lines is very lengthy and occupies at least 3 lines is very lengthy and occupies at least 3 lines\end{minipage}}
\fancyfoot[RE, RO]{\begin{minipage}[c]{1.55cm}\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image-b}\end{minipage}}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancy}}
\setlength{\footskip}{3cm}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

For bottom needs some hacks or other way...

PS: For better results in bottom, `inner sep=0` would help too...